# ResourceBundle not found for MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3

I'm new of spring and now I'm trying to do the I18N process using the aplicationContext. I'm working with a maven modular project. My project countains the following sub-modules:

model-myApp
services-myApp
webApp-myApp

```
services-MyApp
   src/main/java     
   src/main/resources
```

In the services-myApp resources folder I declared the application context with the message source

```
<!-- Need to I18N  -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/lang/myFile"/>
</bean>
```

In the webApp I have the file necessary to I18N

webApp-MyApp
     src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lang/myFile_it_IT.properties

Now when i try to get the message:

```
        String message = applicationContext.getMessage("myCode", null,null, Locale.ITALY);
```

I instead get

> WARN  ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [/WEB-INF/lang/myFile] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/lang/myFile, locale it_IT

and the message is null. While if I move the file in the webApp classpath (/src/main/resources) and change the value of the messageSource to **myFile** everything works.

How can i to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) instead of ResourceBundleMessageSource. It will look for the files under WEB-INF.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I'm learning Spring boot and the configuration for localization took me a while to get it working.

Especially finding the right place for the properties files was a problem. Placing them in `src/main/resources/` is good because it's easy to set the reference to that location. (see gist)

It's also important to know that the basename in `ResourceBundleMessageSource` is automatically relative to the resources path.

If you like to use the configuration annotation based instead of XML. Please check my Gist for an example configuration.

https://gist.github.com/AWolf81/d3ca839e711810345e42